# Having trouble with understand the following derived equation by Euler Theorem..

Tags: cryptography, chinese-remainder-theorem

> We have the following equations 
>   $$\begin{align}
> d_p=&\ d\mod{(p-1)}\tag5 \\ 
>  d_q=&\ d\mod{(q-1)}\tag 6 \\ 
>  x_p=&\ y^{d_p}\mod p\tag 7 \\
> x_q=&\ y^{d_q}\mod q\tag 8  \\
> x=&\ M_pqx_p+M_qpx_q\mod n\tag 9
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Combining (5) and (7) gives $$x_p=y^{d\mod{(p-1)}}\mod p\tag{10}$$ Since $p$ is prime, $\phi(p)=p-1$. According to Euler's theorem, if $\gcd(a,p)=1$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, which implies $$y^d=y^{\lfloor d/(p-1)\rfloor(p-1)+d\mod{(p-1)}}\equiv y^{d\mod{(p-1)}}\pmod p\tag{11}$$

I am having trouble with how the equation (11) is derived.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this without knowing what $x_p$ is.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Equation $(11)$ literally just combines $(5)$ and $(7)$ (as the text says).  So far, nothing to do with $(10)$.  Now, you could use $(10)$ to conclude that $x_p\equiv y^d\pmod p$ but so far the text hasn't taken that step.

Comment: edited.. I just don't understand how the equation 11 is derived by Euler Theorem.

Comment: $x^p=y^{d_p} \pmod p$ by $(7)$.  $d_p=d\pmod {p-1}$ by $(5)$  Now, it isn't even obvious that that makes sense....how can raise $y$ to a congruence class?  Happily Euler's Theorem tells us that $\pmod p$, $y^d$ depends only on $d\pmod {p-1}$.  Thus it makes sense to compute $x^{d_p}\pmod p$ and we get $x^p=y^{d\pmod {p-1}}$ by $(5)$.  To me the question isn't really derivation...it's just interpreting what the terms mean.

Comment: To be clear...I don't like the way your text writes the formulas.  you can't, for example, write $7^{3\pmod {5}} \pmod {13}$.  Why not?  well...$7^3=5\pmod {13}$  but $7^8=3 \pmod {13}$ despite the fact that $3=8\pmod 5$.  Now, because of Euler's Theorem, what the text writes makes sense...but on its face it is not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponent of the middle expression

$\lfloor d/(p-1)\rfloor (p-1)+d\mod(p-1)$

is expressing $d$ as an integer multiple of $(p-1)$ plus its remainder. The significance of this is that, by Euler's Theorem, $y^{p-1}\cong 1\mod p$, hence, using exponent rules, we have that:

$y^{\lfloor d/(p-1)\rfloor (p-1)+d\mod p}$

$=y^{\lfloor d/(p-1)\rfloor (p-1)}\cdot y^{d\mod (p-1)}$

$=(y^{(p-1)})^{\lfloor d/(p-1)\rfloor}\cdot y^{d\mod (p-1)}$

$\cong 1^{\lfloor d/(p-1)\rfloor}\cdot y^{d\mod (p-1)}\mod p$

$=1\cdot y^{d\mod (p-1)}\mod p$

$=y^{d\mod (p-1)}\mod p$